# Filter List of Numbers Using a List of Ranges

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a List of ages and a List of ageRanges, using javascript I am tying to filter the ages that fall within ***any*** of the ageRanges

I got code working for a single ageRange, but how can I do this if ageRanges is an array?

Example of code I used with a single ageRange:

```
 var ages = [32, 33, 16, 22, 40];

var ageRanges = {min: 10, max:23};

function checkAdult(age) {
  return age >= ageRanges.min && age <= ageRanges.max;
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ages.filter(checkAdult);
} //returns 16,22
```

Example of the data I want to filter:

```
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 22, 40];

var ageRanges = [{min: 10, max:23},{min:30, max:36},{min:44, max:49}];
```

I tried doing a for loop, but struggled to get it right as I'm definitely new to all this so any help would be appreciated. Also started to wonder if a for loop was even the riI can easily format the ageRanges data differently if there is a better way to represent a list of ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) along with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const ages = [32, 33, 16, 22, 40],
      ageRanges = [{min: 10, max:23},{min:30, max:36},{min:44, max:49}],
      
      result = ages.filter(age => 
        ageRanges.some(({min,max}) => 
          age >= min && age <= max))
          
console.log(result)
```